# Django The login is successful, but the user information cannot be read when the page is changed?

Tags: python, django

oh,f**k ,I solved this problem all afternoon 
State of mind explosion,I think I'm going crazy.
This mistake hasn't been met before, but it is today.

ok,but,i don't know how to solve.
i login my blogs,flush

## my view.py login:

```
class LoginView(View):
    #todo login
    def get(self,request):
        is_active = "login"
        return render(request, 'login.html', {"is_active": is_active})

    # login
    def post(self,request):

        loginform= LoginForm(request.POST)
        if loginform.is_valid():
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            pass_word = request.POST.get('password', '')
            user = myauthenticate(request,email,pass_word)
            if user:
                login(request,user)

                return render(request,'home.html',{'user':user})

            else:
                return render(request,'login.html',{'msg':"user account or password error"})
        else:
            return render(request,'login.html',{'msg':LoginForm.errors})
```

## my base.html

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li style="float:right;"><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" >注销</a></li>
                    <li class="{% ifequal is_active 'login' %}active{% endifequal %}" style="float:right;">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ user.image }}" width="20" height="20">
                            {{ user.username }}

                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{% url 'users:user_info' user.username %}">用户中心</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">我的粉丝</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">我的收藏</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">我的关注</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'blog:myblogs' %}">我的博客</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="{% ifequal is_active 'login' %}active{% endifequal %}" style="float:right;"><a href="{% url 'users:login' %}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">登录/注册</a></li>
                {% endif %}
```

## in my settings,my middleware is open:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'quwen_users',
    "pythons",
    'blog',
    'captcha',
    "pure_pagination"
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

When I log in to my blog, I click on other pages, and my user information disappears. As you can see, my settings.py configuration is normal, but the Django version has been changed. From Django 2 to Django 1.9, and then from Django 1.9 to Django 2, it's like this.

sorry,Forgive me for my poor English.
thanks guys!

Comment: Please show your `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: what mean, what TEMPLATES ,In settings.py or templates?

Comment: In `settings.py`

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - [edit] the original question. The `TEMPLATES` looks OK to me (I thought perhaps `context_processors.auth` was missing). Please show one of the views where the login information does not appear. Django comes with [authentications views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) including a login view. It's more secure to use Django's login view, and it might solve this issue. How do you import `login`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are passing the `user` as context variable to your **home** page. So you don't have access to `user` in other pages.

If you are using (or extending) django's user model, then you can get the `username` using `{{ request.user.username }}` in *all* of your templates.

So in your template, just use `{{ request.user.username }}` instead of `{{ user.username }}`; and do the same for other fields as well.

Comment: i know {{request.user.username}}, but it doesn't work. When refreshing, the user's message will  disappear

Comment: What's inside `myauthenticate` method?

Comment: def myauthenticate(request,email=None,password=None):
    user = QuwenUser.objects.get(Q(email=email))
    try:
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except Exception as e:
        return None

Comment: It seems like you are extending the django user model **the wrong way**. Basically, you shouldn't write custom `authenticate` model for your **extended user**. Check [documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/) for more details.

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe I used Django user by mistake.Maybe I'm not familiar with Django's user model, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use django authenticate method

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def custom_login(request):
    user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('email'),
                        password=request.POST.get('password')
    if user:
        login(request, user)
    redirect_url = 'your_url'
    return redirect(redirect_url)
```

Comment: yes , i use authenticate method. but,error not on authenticate,it is in html .
Maybe I don't understand Django user enough.but,thank you answer.